# Qt : how to set text to QSystemTrayIcon?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to dynamically set the text instead of Icon in `QSystemTrayIcon`. How it is possible ?

Comment: How about calling showMessage?

Comment: How can you set text, if it is an **icon**? I rather want to set an image with text inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tray icon is not designed to show text, just small image. 
Also, you can set tooltip message as @Merlin069 said, show balloon message or create context menu.

Of cource, you can create an image in you program and draw some text on it:

```cpp
QPixmap pixmap(24,24);
pixmap.fill(Qt::white);
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
painter.drawText(pixmap.rect(),Qt::AlignCenter,"Hi!");
icon.setIcon(pixmap);
icon.setToolTip("Hi!");
icon.setVisible(true);
```